# How can I set a button style in table cell to have full size?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table :

```
 <table dir="rtl" style="width: 100%;" >
 <tr>
     <td style="width:250px;height:60px">
        <input id="Meal0"  type="button" style="height:60px;width:250px"  />
    </td>
    <td style="width:250px;height:60px">
        <input id="Meal1"  type="button" style="height:60px;width:250px" />
    </td>
    <td style="width:250px;height:60px">
        <input id="Meal2"  type="button" style="height:60px;width:250px"  />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td style="width:250px;height:60px">
        <input id="Meal3"  type="button" style="height:60px;width:250px"  />
    </td>
    <td style="width:250px;height:60px">
        <input id="Meal4"  type="button" style="height:60px;width:250px"  />
    </td>
    <td style="width:250px;height:60px">
        <input id="Meal5"  type="button" style="height:60px;width:250px"  />
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Now,I want to fix the buttons in each cells of a table.but it's not happen !
I Set the size of each `<td> : style="width:250px;height:60px"` and for each button `button :style="width:250px;height:60px"` like each other,but there is margin in each cells,why?

[image]

Comment: try adding `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"` to your table

Comment: What do you mean by `fix the buttons in each cells`?

Comment: Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/zuxL6qty/ or http://jsfiddle.net/y680173r/

Comment: @ Mary Melody:thank you very much.I edit the picture of my question.How can remove Padding-button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I Set the size of each `<td>` [...] and for each button [...] like
>   each other, but there is margin in each cells, why?

There's no margin, in fact table cells share the entire space of the table (which has a `width` of `100%`), so that the computed width would be greater than `250px` in large screens (`> 750px` wide).

If you want the buttons to fill the entire cells, try using so:

**[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/hawayo/3/edit)**

```css
table { table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }
table td { width: 33.33%; height: 60px; }
table td input[type="button"] { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
```

Comment: How can remove Padding-button? I edit the picture,in my question.thanks.@Hashem Qolami

Comment: @Farna Not sure if I've understood correctly but if you mean the space between each cell, you could give `border-collapse: collapse;` to the table - [Example](http://jsbin.com/hawayo/4/edit).